# Não consigo acessar valor de um objeto JSON e exibi-lo na div

Tags: javascript, json, front-end

Estou realizando alguns testes com um arquivo `.json` com a intenção de implementar o código na minha aplicação (caso eu tenha sucesso nos testes). Estou utilizando o seguinte [arquivo json](https://github.com/mdn/learning-area/blob/master/javascript/oojs/json/JSONTest.html).

**Segue o código:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <title>Testando</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: #ccc;
      }
      div {
        width: 40%;
        height: 200px;
        margin: auto;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        margin-top: 50px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
    
    </div>
    
    <script>
      var div = document.querySelector('div');
      var requestURL = 'https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json';
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('GET', requestURL);
      request.responseType = 'json';
      request.send();
      
      request.onload = function(){
        var obras = request.response;
        procuraObra(obras);
      }
      
      function procuraObra(jsonObj){
        var nomeObras = jsonObj['members']['name'];
        
        for (var i = 0; i < nomeObras.length; i++){
          if (nomeObras[i] == 'Madame Uppercut'){
            var resultado = nomeObras[i];
          }
        }
        if (resultado != null){
          var primeiroP = document.createElement('p');
          primeiroP.textContent = resultado;
        }
        div.appendChild(primeiroP);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Explicando a partir das funções:

```
function procuraObra(jsonObj){
  var nomeObras = jsonObj['members']['name'];
```

No trecho acima eu quero guardar a quantidade de nomes, que de acordo com o arquivo que estou usando são 3.
No trecho abaixo eu quero guardar o nome *Madame Uppercut* (ele existe no arquivo).

```
for (var i = 0; i < nomeObras.length; i++){
  if (nomeObras[i] == 'Madame Uppercut'){
    var resultado = nomeObras[i];
  }
}
```

Depois de ter encontrado e salvo o nome, no código abaixo eu crio a `tag <p>` e adiciono o nome encontrado nela (variável resultado):

```
if (resultado != null){
  var primeiroP = document.createElement('p');
  primeiroP.textContent = resultado;
}
```

E por fim adiciono na `div` a `tag <p>` contendo o nome:

```
div.appendChild(primeiroP);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema principal está nesta linha abaixo que você está tentando iterar com `for`:

```
var nomeObras = jsonObj['members']['name'];
```

Na verdade a array é apenas o `jsonObj['members']`, e o `name` é uma chave dos objetos da array, logo a variável `nomeObras` deveria ser:

```
var nomeObras = jsonObj['members'];
```

E no `if` dentro do `for` você irá comparar se a chave `name` é igual à string buscada:

```
if(nomeObras[i].name == 'Madame Uppercut'){...
```

Se o `if` for atendido, a variável resultado deverá ser o valor da chave `name`, e você pode colocar um `break` após a variável `resultado` para interromper o `for`, já que foi encontrado o valor que queria buscar:

```
var resultado = nomeObras[i].name;
break;
```

O código ficará assim:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var requestURL = 'https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();

request.onload = function(){
   var obras = request.response;
   procuraObra(obras);
}

function procuraObra(jsonObj){
   var nomeObras = jsonObj['members'];

   for (var i = 0; i < nomeObras.length; i++){
      if (nomeObras[i].name == 'Madame Uppercut'){
         var resultado = nomeObras[i].name;
         break;
      }
   }
   if (resultado != null){
      var primeiroP = document.createElement('p');
      primeiroP.textContent = resultado;
   }
   div.appendChild(primeiroP);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
div {
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Era exatamente o que eu precisava, agora vou trabalhar com o parse para abstrair ao máximo essa estrutura. valeu!