# Resultado de pesquisa via web service

Tags: javascript, web-service, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou construindo uma aplicação de busca (input) e ele deve trazer o resultado de um webservice.

Exemplo:

```
xhttp.open("POST", "https://www.site.br/api/v1/busca/termo/_pesquisa", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
var data = JSON.stringify({"order":"relevancia","pagina":1,"q":"*"});
xhttp.send(data);
```

O retorno deste código traz o JSON puro do web service e eu gostaria de organizar os dados de acordo com meu HTML, com título, nome e descrição (vindo, claro, do webservice).

Há algum exemplo prático que eu possa fazer? 
Obrigado, desde já.

Comment: se pesquisar aqui no site tem vários exemplos, como esse: [acessar o valor de um objeto json](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/391583/n%C3%A3o-consigo-acessar-valor-de-um-objeto-json-e-exibi-lo-na-div)

Comment: Obrigado, @Ricardo. Resolveu pra mim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode pegar o Json puro e realizar o "parse"

`let jsonData = jsonRetorno.parse();`

E depois vc pode usar o objeto Json:

```js
   console.log(jsonData.titulo);
   console.log(jsonData.nome);
   console.log(jsonData.descricao);
```

Comment: Isso foi bem útil, vou usar daqui pra frente.